# Difference between --parameter-overrides and --tags

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cli

I am having a hard time understanding the difference between --parameter-overrides and --tags when deploying an AWS stack using CloudFormation.
I tried to read through the documentation but I still do not understand, I seem to get exactly the same behaviour when I use the cli to deploy my stack with the usage of one or the other flag, such as

```
      aws --profile $PROFILE cloudformation deploy
      --stack-name ${STACK_NAME}
      --template-file $TEMPLATE_FILE
      --parameter-overrides
      ApplicationName=$APP_NAME
      --no-fail-on-empty-changeset
      --tags
      ApplicationName=$APP_NAME
```

When and why would I use the tags? Any help?

Comment: `--parameter-overrides` overrides things defined in the `Parameters` section of your cloudformation template. Tags just adds tags to created resources.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`--tags` set arbitrary [Tags](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws_tagging.html) on the Stack.   Tags are key-value metadata for labelling and categorizing AWS resources.  Tags are optional.  They do not affect how CloudFormation deploys the stack.

[--parameter-overrides](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/cloudformation/deploy.html#options) inject [parameter](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/parameters-section-structure.html) values into the template.  Optional if you are happy with the template's parameter defaults (for new deploys) or currently deployed values (for updates).